# Uploading smaller files with multipart file upload with only one part using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have configured AWS S3 and a lambda function which triggers when a file is inserted into S3. I have configured an event s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload in lambda to trigger. When I tested through AWS CLI with large files it worked. But when I upload a smaller file with size less than 5 MB, the event is not triggering the lambda. How can I do this for small size files with only one part?
Anyone please help....

Answer (score 1):

Files less than 5MB cannot be uploaded using multipart upload. Therefore, you can add `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` event to let your lambda get notified too.